# trying to insert data in table in postgreSQL. Everything is working fine with no error but there is no row visible in actually table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a table. It gives (Failed to insert record  unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) ) error and no row is getting inserted into table

```
import psycopg2
try:
i=0
tempcol0="a"
tempcol1="b"
tempcol2="c"
tempcol3="d"
tempcol4="e"
tempcol5="f"
tempcol6="g"
tempcol7="h"
tempcol8="i"
tempcol9="j"
tempcol10="k"
tempcol11="l"
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection details)
cur = conn.cursor()
postgres_insert_query = '''INSERT INTO desktop1(id, column0, column1, column2, column3, column4, 

column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11) VALUES(%d,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);'''
    record_to_insert = (i, tempcol0, tempcol1, tempcol2, tempcol3, tempcol4, tempcol5, tempcol6, tempcol7, tempcol8, tempcol9, tempcol10, tempcol11)
    cur.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
    conn.commit()
    count = cur.rowcount
    print(count, " row inserted into table");
except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    if (conn):
        print("Failed to insert record ", error)

finally:
    if(conn):
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: What is the datatype for column3 ?

Comment: @VynlJunkie all are text except id which is int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string interpolation issue. You are attempting to pass a numeric value as part of a String. The '%d' as actually treated as a string. Change it to '%s' and it will work.

```
import psycopg2

i=0
tempcol0="a"
tempcol1="b"
tempcol2="c"
tempcol3="c"
tempcol4="e"
tempcol5="f"
tempcol6="g"
tempcol7="h"
tempcol8="i"
tempcol9="j"
tempcol10="k"
tempcol11="l"
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgres user=postgres')
cur = conn.cursor()
postgres_insert_query = '''INSERT INTO test(id, tempcol0, tempcol1,tempcol2, tempcol3, tempcol4,tempcol5, tempcol6, tempcol7, tempcol8, tempcol9,tempcol10,tempcol11) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
record_to_insert = (i, tempcol0, tempcol1, tempcol2, tempcol3, tempcol4, tempcol5, tempcol6, tempcol7, tempcol8, tempcol9, tempcol10, tempcol11)
cur.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
conn.commit()
```

---

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (12.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select * from test ;
 id | tempcol0 | tempcol1 | tempcol2 | tempcol3 | tempcol4 | tempcol5 | tempcol6 | tempcol7 | tempcol8 | tempcol9 | tempcol10 | tempcol11 
----+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------
  0 | a        | b        | c        | c        | e        | f        | g        | h        | i        | j        | k         | l
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: pint is I have to process a whole file. When I do it in loop everything works no error but it does not inserts data into actual table in database. I still cannot understand why.